# laravel eloquent where clause with pivot

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.4, eloquent

i have three table like below :

```
members
---------
id | tag | hasOn
1  |  1  |   1
2  |  2  |   1
3  |  3  |   0
4  |  1  |   1

tags
---------
id | title | date
1  |   a   |   05.12.2017 00:00:00
2  |   b   |   01.12.2017 00:00:00
3  |   c   |   12.11.2017 00:00:00
4  |   d   |   27.11.2017 00:00:00
```

and has a pivot table

```
member_tag
-------------
member_id | tag_id | tagActive
    1     |    1   |    1
    1     |    2   |    1
    1     |    3   |    0
    1     |    4   |    1
    2     |    1   |    1
    2     |    2   |    1
    2     |    3   |    1
    2     |    4   |    1
```

this is my code ( Auth::user referred to Member Model )

> Auth::user()->tags()->where('date', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->orWhere(function($q){
>       $q->wherePivot('tagActive', 1);
>   })->first();

it is not working.
i have to checkout member tags by "date < now" or "tagActive = 1"

> how could i do this? ( check it out where to own table column or where to pivot table column)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: QueryBuilder::wherePivot not exists

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order, so you can do this:

```
Auth::user()->tags()
    ->wherePivot('tagActive', 1)
    ->orWhere('date', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
    ->first();
```

`wherePivot` only exists on a `BelongsToMany` relation. It does not exist on a scopeless QueryBuilder, and that is what you get in a where clause with a closure.

Comment: ->wherePivot does not work in BelongsToMany